# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-5,25"

Tags: java, android, instagram

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string
```

This is my code:

```
private void setDepth(GL10 gl){
    float max = -5.25f;
    float min = -6.25f;
    float A = (max - min) / 2;
    float z;
    double temp = A * -Math.abs(Math.sin(2 * (round(angleRectangle) * pi / 180))) + max;
    String s = String.format("%.2f", temp).trim();
    z = Float.parseFloat(s);
    depth = z;
}
```

Comment: Given this code, I don't get the error you are talking about. Please give more info

Comment: Hi thanks thanks for respond I try to implemented story of instagram clone in this https://github.com/mitchtabian/Android-Instagram-Clone/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tabian/com/instagramclone2/opengl/MyGLRenderer.java

Answer (score 0):

You probably have put a ',' instead of a '.'. Java and other programming only like '-5.25'.

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear to me that the backend is expecting there a number and that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format("%.2f", temp)` will use the current system locale. To quote the method Javadoc:

> The locale always used is the one returned by java.util.Locale#getDefault()

Your code will work when default locale is English, which can be tested by using overloaded version of `String.format()`:

```
String s = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", temp).trim();
z = Float.parseFloat(s); // works, a dot is used for fractions separator
```

but will fail if for example German locale is set as default:

```
String s = String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%.2f", temp).trim();
z = Float.parseFloat(s); // fails, a comma is used for fractions separator
```

As `Float.parseFloat()` doesn't support the concept of locale you have to ensure that you are using `String.format()` to produce format expected by it. One way to ensure that your code will work regardless of the default locale is to use the [`Locale.ROOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) constant:

```
String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", temp)
```

Comment: Oh thanks I didnt understand  what I could do then ?

Comment: Ah  I didnt understand the answer "you have to ensure that you are using  String.format() to produce format expected by it."

Comment: @Erik you need to understand how the `Locale` works in Java if you plan to use it. I updated the answer with `Locale.ROOT` suggestion but you should review the docs to figure out what you want to do.